# How can I do "Show my location" on Daum maps?

Tags: geolocation

[Google maps](http://maps.google.com) has a geolocation feature called ["show my location"](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=153802) which detects where you are based on your IP address or cellular phone network data and centres the map accordingly.

Here in South Korea, [Daum maps](http://map.daum.net/) coverage and detail is much better than Google Maps, but as my Korean skills are basic, I can't seem to find the geolocation feature.

It's possible I suppose that they don't have such a feature but I doubt it because it's otherwise a very advanced and very polished website.

(I've now also asked this very same question about Korea's other major mapping webapp, [Naver](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31537/how-can-i-do-show-my-location-on-naver-maps).)

Comment: They have it as a feature in their API for Mobile Map.

Comment: @Alex: What does the icon for it look like so I can look for it in their webapp?

Comment: I don’t know, I found the info on [this presentation for the API](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=daum%20maps%20current%20location&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdaumdna.tistory.com%2Fattachment%2Fcfile27.uf%4020789544502316611C0024.pdf&ei=SoBbUMWEDqPe4QSKhYH4Aw&usg=AFQjCNHIfFxTNtoBR91vP2PfO4eA_Eb2ug).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether still relevant five years later! (Tagged [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) it has probably been "under the horizon" for many.)

From [whereismimiyu](https://whereismimiyu.wordpress.com/2015/05/15/best-korean-map-apps/) (15 May, 2015):

> On the left upper side there is a button that will show you your current locations (if GPS is on and you accepted the condition of daum map using your gps).

This is the same position as for Naver Maps - which you link to but is now `404`. (Odd, if the same Q as this, just different 'supplier'.):

[image: WA31345 example]

(*Image courtesy* [Joy](https://12amflight.com/2014/01/11/howtonavermap/))

Sorry, not found a usable DaumMaps image.

Note that there is now an [English interface](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kakao-map-daummaps-4-0/id304608425?mt=8) to Kakao Map (DaumMaps 4.0).